# How Can I use Decimals here to change position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform x;
    public int moving = 1;
    public GameObject Thing;
    public Vector3 Offset;

    void Start () {

    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        x.transform.position = Thing.transform.position + Offset ;

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {

            Thing.transform.Translate(+1,0,0);


        }
```

I don't know why But Here at "Thing.transform.Translate" I can't use decimal numbers. Is There Any way around this problem ?

[The Cube Needs to move in Decimals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCIlZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `float` number in Unity needs to be followed by a cast expressed with a `f`.

```
Thing.transform.Translate(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f);
```

Comment: ok But I can only use float for decimal number like 1.5f how do i add 1.55 ?

Comment: You can add a number with multiple decimal digits the same way `Thing.transform.Translate(1.55f, 1.55f, 1.55f);`